# Stata: collect scalars (eg test statistics) into one object

Tags: stata, scalar, postfile

This should be very easy but I can't find a good answer:

I want to collect a number of scalars, for example the means of several variables (or regression outputs, or test statistics, or p-values), into one object to be used in plotting or as a variable etc.

Consider a dataset like:

```
clear
input str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 12
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
end
```

Say I get the scalars I want to collect from a loop:

```
foreach i in var1 var2 var3{
mean `i'
matrix A= r(table)
scalar s_`i'= A[1,1]
}
```

Now I can `display s_var1` for example but how do I get an object which simply gives me `[9, 9.3333, 7.6666]` to use for plotting or as a variable? Ideally without losing the original dataset? Of course, my actual dataset is not 3x3 but much longer.

**Edit:** After clarifications in the comments, the most straightforward answer is in Robertos Edit. Ander2ed's answer give intuition towards programming the problem directly.

Comment: What exactly do you want to graph? How would that graph look like? What graph commands do you intend to use?

Comment: How big is your dataset? Does Stata take a "significant" amount of time to load it?

Comment: Graph commands take variables, so that's probably what you should aim for. How you get there is another matter, but I sense more information is needed for you to receive a specific solution to your problem.

Comment: I want to do bar diagrams with very few observations (maximum 10) and the dataset has around 200 variables of less than 2000 observations so size should be no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the data to create a graph ultimately depends on the structure of your dataset, required computations, (maybe) the size of your dataset, and the type of graph.

A nonsensical example:

```
clear
input str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 12
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
end

preserve

collapse var*

gen i = _n
reshape long var, i(i)

graph twoway line var _j

restore
```

`collapse` here is an example of some computation, but it can be anything. I use `preserve` and `restore` to easily go back to the original data. This may or may not be the best approach, but like I mentioned before, it really depends on the problem at hand.

### Edit

In response to your comment, you probably want `postfile`. An example (pretty much from the manual):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 12
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
end

*----- what you want -----

tempfile results

tempname sim
postfile `sim' mean var using `results', replace
quietly {
    foreach v of varlist var? {
        summarize `v'
        post `sim' (r(mean)) (r(Var))
    }
}
postclose `sim'
list // original ok

use `results', clear
list // results to graph
```

`postfile` is very flexible. Just read the manual entry and experiment.

Comment: ok, I think I have to re-think a little from R... Collapse can, of course, not be replaced by other operators very easily in your example. Say I want the correlations instead of the mean, it would not work. My idea is to build a code which does some test/regression/statistic, collects one element of the resulting r() matrix and adds it as an element to a vector before doing the same thing for the next variable. That way, I'd build a vector of these results and I can easily adapt the code to whatever statistic I want.

Comment: Try `help statsby` and `help postfile`. See also their respective manual entries (the `help` files have links to those).

Comment: I think the comment "I have to re-think a little from R" is revealing here. Stata certainly has classes (`help class`) but to do what you want you would need to do all the programming yourself. Saved results are typically saved one by one, not in a bag of any kind.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `collapse` as suggested by @Roberto's answer, I often use Stata's `matrix` language, particularly `svmat`, for similar tasks. I think here it is a matter of preference (although `collapse` may be more direct) so I thought it worth mentioning in a separate, nonsensical example:

```
clear *
input str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 12
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
end

mean var1 - var3
mat A = (r(table))'

preserve
clear

svmat A, names(matcol)
rename A* *

// Build Plots Here
twoway scatter t pvalue, name(plot1)

restore

graph display plot1
```